# How Spring Security detects the password filed?

Tags: java, database, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing an web application using java with Spring MVC and Sprin-Security. I can see, Spring Security does the authentication and security related tasks by itself which is OK. I was wondering how Spring Security detects the password field from database on which the authentication is made!!!

I have stored the user passwords in a column named 'xyz'. Now, how can I ask Spring-Security to look for user password in the column 'xyz'???? I tried to find a clear answer for this, but couldn't. So, if you guys please help me to make a clear concept about this.... I appreciate that!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to setup JDBC Connectivity. For that you can use Spring JDBC so that the connections are spring managed.

Then, you need to override UserDetailsService of Spring Security to your own queries. An example is given [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/custom-userdetailsservice-example-for-spring-3-security/)

Then wire your services either via programmatic configuration or via XML configuration, whichever way you have done it in your project.

Comment: Thanks @aksappy. I saw the example you provided above. But I couldn't find my answer. Simply my question is how can I ask Spring Security to check for user Password in a specific column???

Comment: By using an SQL Query, fetch the password and then match it with the requested password.

Comment: aksappy, Can I please ask you one more question?? 
the "password" in the code "UserDetails user = new User(username, "password", true, true, true, true, new GrantedAuthority[]{ new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER") })" is the requested password or the password fetched from database??

Comment: Anytime mate, go ahead

Comment: Again- the question : The "password" in the code UserDetails user = new User(username, "password", true, true, true, true, new GrantedAuthority[]{ new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER") }) is the requested password or the password fetched from database??

Comment: That "password" is a hardcoded one. You will have to fetch the password from the database and assign it.